What does it mean "The scene struck him immediately and forcibly, cutting through the beer haze like the flick of a wet towel"
It's from Salem's lot by Stephen King. I'm not interested in a Google translation. I want to be able to read similar texts like a native English speaker.

beer: Is it the beer we drink
flick: does it mean movie or movement like the dictionary says.
wet towel: what has it to do with anything.

Maybe he saw a fuzzy image through a glass like the glass of a beer, that's why it's haze?
For more context here is the sentence in more length:

He pushed open the door and walked in.
The scene struck him immediately and forcibly, cutting through the beer haze like the flick of a wet towel: the baby, naked and screaming, blood running from his nose;


Note that beer haze (fuzzy / poor eyesight caused by being drunk) isn't really an established idiom. Even native Anglophones just have to work that one out from context. But beer goggles (you're drunk, so you think the stranger you're chatting up is more attractive than they really are) is a well-established informal usage.

It is not uncommon, or at least it used to be not uncommon, that in the communal shower in a US high school after gym class, especially at an all-boys school, some Malfoy-type would be snapping his wet towel at someone's thigh or backside. The wet towel makes a snapping sound like a whip, and if it is done by someone who has mastered the dubious art, it can sting like hell and leave a welt.   It wakes you up "real good".

@FumbleFingers beer haze isn't an idiom per se, but many dictionaries seem to recognize haze as relating to impaired perception or memory - of which the poor eyesight is a part of, but not the only one.

@MaciejStachowski: If you like it and it works for you, that's fine. Personally, I think it's a crap metaphor. I had to think to get that meaning, since my initial automatic reaction was hazy cigarette smoke in a beery bar. So for me the imagery completely missed its target, and it's not the kind of thing where the writer gets a second chance to have the intended impact. On the other hand, given that anyone born after 2009 will now never be legally able to smoke anywhere in the UK, perhaps I'm just showing my age! :)

...I notice that the OP here never thought of "beer haze" as being caused by intoxication (which gives you double vision, not "fuzzy" focus). Maybe it's really a "twice-removed" metaphor, where the subject's mind is befogged by booze.

@FumbleFingers At least in the US, the phrase "drug-induced haze" is common, so a "beer haze" is just a specific example of that more general phenomenon.

@CanadianYankee: I don't know of any "recreational" drugs that cause fuzzy / hazy vision - and like I say, alcohol definitely doesn't do that. But there's no point in people telling me why the cited usage works for them. It didn't work for me, and given the whole point of a metaphor is to get the message across strikingly and/or succinctly, I label this one as a "failure".

@FumbleFingers I don't read the original as talking about vision at all. From definition 3 of "haze": "a mental state in which your thoughts, feelings, etc. are not clear; an alcoholic haze".  There's no metaphor here at all - an unclear mental state is just one of the documented definitions of the word "haze" (though it presumably originated as a metaphor) and the dictionary even lists "alcoholic haze" as an example. Your unfamiliarity with this meaning of the word is not the fault of the author.

@CanadianYankee: We're going round iin circles. Obviously I know all relevant meanings of the word "haze". But the cited metaphor (which it unquestionably is, whatever precise meaning you attach to it) didn't work "transparently" for me, so I don't rate it very highly. And as a Lit Crit graduate, I feel I have the credentials to make such a judgement (for myself, if not for others).

@FumbleFingers I think it's more of a UK/US difference. "Haze" as in "chemically-induced brain fog" is in much more more common usage in America than in Britain. For example, the phrase "drug-induced haze" occurs exactly once at bbc.com (in an article about an American!) and 46 times at nytimes.com. The phrase "alcoholic haze" is similarly skewed (2 versus 50 times). ("Beer haze" Is impossible to search because it's also a literal phrase describing the opacity of some beers.) Stephen King is an American author and is thus using the word "haze" that's evocative to the American ear.

"The scene" is whatever he saw. I haven't read the book so I have no idea what that is. From what follows, I guess it was something surprising or horrifying.
Yes, "beer" here refers to the beer you drink. A "beer haze" is when you have had so much beer that you are drunk and can no longer see or think clearly. So your vision and your mind are a haze.
"Flick" here refers to a quick motion, usually throwing or hitting something. To "flick someone with a towel" is to hold a towel in your hand, and then make a snapping motion to hit them with it. As a towel is pretty soft this wouldn't hurt someone, but it could startle them. Especially a wet towel. Being hit with something soft and wet is jarring, the kind of thing that would wake you up if you were dozing off ... or that would snap you back to alertness if you were in a beer haze.
So he's not saying that anyone literally hit him with a towel. Rather, he's saying that the scene was so shocking that it was LIKE being hit with a wet towel. And that this shocked him out of his drunken state from consuming too much beer.

"The flick of a wet towel" is an insult but also a bit painful. It's locker room activity. Like the beer haze.

Make sense. The guy in question was drunk in the novel. Thanks

Someone has never been hit with a wet towel :) It might be soft, but the locker room "tradition" is to twist it and snap it at someone's (usually bare) posterior like a whip - and I can attest to it that it can hurt a lot.

@MaciejStachowski Okay, doesn't hurt A LOT. As in, it's not like being hit with a brick or stabbed with a knife. :-)
